# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' , cuando intento enviar un mensaje con un bot a un canal de discord específico

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, atributos, discord.py

Intenté enviar un mensaje con el bot de *Discord* a un canal de texto específico, de varias formas, pero ninguna de las tantas que probé realmente funcionó para mí.

Aquí les dejo las formas que intento con los respectivos errores que devuelve para cada code que hice pero ninguno me funciona...

### #1

```py
import time, random, discord
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@bot.command()
async def time_messege(args):
    
    alarmtime = "20:54"
    

    #greeting_channel = bot.get_channel("814238156396298310")


    client = discord.Client()


    while True:
      
        lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

        if lcltime == alarmtime:

            #aca pondria el code de detectar canal y enviar
            print("is time!")

            random_num = random.randint(1, 4)

            if random_num == 1:
                #await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, como estan chic@s?")
                await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "Holi!, como estan chic@s?")
            elif random_num == 2:
                #await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, oCmo va su dia? que me cuentan?")
                await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "Holi!, oCmo va su dia? que me cuentan?")
            elif random_num == 3:
                #await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?")
                await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?")
            elif random_num == 4:
                #await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, como se encuentran?")
                await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "Holi!, como se encuentran?")

            time.sleep(90)

        else:
            print("not yet")
            time.sleep(10)
```

**Error**

```
not yet
not yet
not yet
is time!
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 101, in between_callback
    loop.run_until_complete(time_messege(args))
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in __call__
    return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Desktop\h ver 18-03\SmartBot-main\core\modules\greetings.py", line 41, in time_messege
    await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "Holi!, como se encuentran?")
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

### #2

si utilizo el otro código (el código comentado, y no el del client) da un error similar:

```py
import time, random, discord
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands


async def time_messege(args):
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
    alarmtime = "19:36"
    
    greeting_channel = bot.get_channel("814238156396298310")
    #channel = bot.get_channel = xxx

    #client = discord.Client()


    while True:
      
        lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

        if lcltime == alarmtime:

            #aca pondria el code de detectar canal y enviar
            print("is time!")

            random_num = random.randint(1, 4)

            if random_num == 1:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, como estan chic@s?")
                #await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "Holi!, como estan chic@s?")
            elif random_num == 2:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, oCmo va su dia? que me cuentan?")
                #await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "Holi!, oCmo va su dia? que me cuentan?")
            elif random_num == 3:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?")
                #await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?")
            elif random_num == 4:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, como se encuentran?")
                #await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "Holi!, como se encuentran?")

            time.sleep(90)

        else:
            print("not yet")
            time.sleep(10)
```

**Error**

```
not yet
not yet
not yet
is time!
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 101, in between_callback
    loop.run_until_complete(time_messege(args))
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Desktop\h ver 18-03\SmartBot-main\core\modules\greetings.py", line 33, in time_messege
    await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, oCmo va su dia? que me cuentan?")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

¿Qué algoritmo me recomiendan y qué debo hacer para evitar estos errores? ¿Qué atributo debo poner?

Yo uso esa versión de discord library:

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import discord
>>> discord.__version__
'1.6.0'
```

---

**ACTUALIZACION DE LA PREGUNTA**

Intente poner el id como un valor numerico aun asi sigue dando error:

```py
import time, random, discord
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

#bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

#@bot.command()
async def time_messege(args):
    
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')    
    alarmtime = "11:13"
    
    #El comando espera el id del canal en forma de un entero, no en forma de cadena
    greeting_channel = bot.get_channel(814238156396298310)

    #client = discord.Client()


    while True:
      
        lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

        if lcltime == alarmtime:

            #aca pondria el code de detectar canal y enviar
            print("is time!")

            random_num = random.randint(1, 4)

            if random_num == 1:
                await greeting_channel.send("@everyone Holi!, como estan chic@s?")
                #await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "@everyone Holi!, como estan chic@s?")
            elif random_num == 2:
                await greeting_channel.send("@everyone Holi!, Como va su dia? que me cuentan?")
                #await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "@everyone Holi!, oCmo va su dia? que me cuentan?")
            elif random_num == 3:
                await greeting_channel.send("@everyone Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?")
                #await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "@everyone Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?")
            elif random_num == 4:
                await greeting_channel.send("@everyone Holi!, como se encuentran?")
                #await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='814238156396298310'), "@everyone Holi!, como se encuentran?")

            time.sleep(90)

        else:
            print("not yet")
            time.sleep(10)
```

**Error**

```
not yet
not yet
not yet
not yet
not yet
is time!
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 101, in between_callback
    loop.run_until_complete(time_messege(args))
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Desktop\h ver 18-03\SmartBot-main\core\modules\greetings.py", line 34, in time_messege
    await greeting_channel.send("@everyone Holi!, Como va su dia? que me cuentan?")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

---

**ACTUALIZACION #2**

```py
# CÓDIGO MODIFICADO BASADO EN MIS RECOMENDACIONES
import time, random, discord, asyncio # Importo asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents(guilds=True)) # Uso el segundo método para establecer los intents

@bot.command()
async def time_messege(ctx): # Se le suele llamar así a este primer argumento en la documentación, no es obligatorio pero sirve para guiarse
    
    alarmtime = "16:32"
    
    #El comando espera el id del canal en forma de un entero, no en forma de cadena
    greeting_channel = bot.get_channel(842414327495655441)

    while True:
      
        lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

        if lcltime == alarmtime:

            #aca pondria el code de detectar canal y enviar
            print("is time!")

            hello_strings = ("@everyone Holi!, como estan chic@s?", "@everyone Holi!, Como va su dia? que me cuentan?", "everyone Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?", "@everyone Holi!, como se encuentran?") # Pongo las opciones de texto en una tupla y luego elijo una al azar con random.choice

            await greeting_channel.send(random.choice(hello_strings))

            await asyncio.sleep(90)

        else:
            print("not yet")
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

**Error**

```
not yet
not yet
not yet
is time!
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 101, in between_callback
    loop.run_until_complete(time_messege(args))
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in __call__
    return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Desktop\h ver 18-03\SmartBot-main\core\modules\greetings.py", line 27, in time_messege
    await greeting_channel.send(random.choice(hello_strings))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

---

**ACTUALIZACION #3**

Este es el script main del bot, con esto envia mensjaes a aquellos usuarios que le escriben y el otro script que falla es el de enviar un mensaje solo en automatica cada cierto tiempo por eso hice otro thread.

```py
import discord, json, os
import datetime, random, time

#Para poner mensajes por tiempo
from core.modules.greetings import time_messege
import threading
import asyncio

main_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

""" Load Bot Configurations """
config_path = os.path.join(main_path, "config.json")
with open(config_path, "r") as jsonfile:
    bot_config = json.load(jsonfile)

from core.smartbot import SmartBot
from core.modules.bot_brain import BotBrain
from core.modules.bot_actions import BotActions

bot_modules = [BotBrain, BotActions]
ChatBot = SmartBot(bot_config, bot_modules, main_path)

class BotClient(discord.Client):
    @staticmethod
    def is_DMChannel(message: str) -> bool:
        """Verifica si es un mensaje proveniente es de un canal privado"""
        return isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel)

    def save_log(self, response: str, message: object) -> None:
        """Guarda el historial de conversacion"""
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        file_path = os.path.join(main_path, f"assets/log/{date.strftime('%d%b%y')}.txt")

        with open(file_path, "a", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
            text_file.write(f"{message.content}\n{response}\n")

    def load_content(self, name: str) -> dict:
        """Carga contenido .json de la carpeta embeds"""
        embed_path = os.path.join(main_path, f"assets/embeds/{name}.json")
        with open(embed_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as jsonfile:
            content = json.load(jsonfile)

        return content

    def create_embed(self, content: dict) -> object:
        """Crea un embed basado en el contenido de un diccionario"""
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=content["title"],
            description=content["description"],
            color=int(content["color"], 16),
        )

        embed.set_thumbnail(url=content["icon_url"])

        for key, value in content["content"].items():
            embed.add_field(name=key, value=value, inline=content["inline"])

        embed.set_footer(text=content["footer"])

        return embed

    def create_response(self, message: object) -> list:
        """Crea una respuesta en base al mensaje, y le da formato usando embeds"""

        response = ChatBot(message.content, str(message.author.id))
        if response != "#NoText":
            embed_content = self.load_content("msg_container")

            face_images = self.load_content("icon_urls")
            state = ChatBot.user_data[str(message.author.id)]["state"]
            if state in face_images:
                embed_content["icon_url"] = face_images[state]
            else:
                embed_content["icon_url"] = random.choice(list(face_images.values()))

            embed_content["description"] = f"`{response}`"
            embed = self.create_embed(embed_content)
        else:
            embed = None
        return response, embed

    async def send_response(self, message: object, is_server=False) -> None:
        """Envia una respuesta por el canal de proveniencia del mensaje."""
        response, embed = self.create_response(message)
        if bot_config["DebugMode"]:
            self.save_log(response, message)
            print(f"{message.author}: {message.content}")
            print(f"@ Bot: {response}")

        if response and response != "#notext" and embed:
            if is_server:
                await message.reply(embed=embed)
            else:
                await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


    def between_callback(self, args):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

        loop.run_until_complete(time_messege(args))
        loop.close()


    #Ese metodo se ejecuta automaticamente cada vez que el bot se enciende
    async def on_ready(self) -> None:

        print("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user))

        #x = threading.Thread(target=time_messege) #Creo un thread independiente del main_thread
        #x.start()

        _thread = threading.Thread(target=self.between_callback, args=("some text", ))
        _thread.start()


    async def on_message(self, message: object) -> None:
        if not message.author.bot:
            if message.content.startswith(bot_config["prefix"]):
                args = message.content.split(" ", 1)
                command = args[0][len(bot_config["prefix"]):]

                if command.lower() == "fit":
                    ChatBot.fit(args[1], str(message.author.id))

            else:
                if self.is_DMChannel(message):
                    await self.send_response(message)

                elif not self.is_DMChannel(message) and self.user in message.mentions:
                    await self.send_response(message, is_server=True)


def ConsoleChat():
    """Permite utilizar al bot en la consola"""
    fake_user = "Anonimous"
    while True:
        text = input("User >> ")
        if text.lower() == "exit":
            break
        else:
            response = ChatBot(text, fake_user)
            if response != "#NoText":
                print(f"Bot: {response}")
            else:
                print("*Parece que el bot no quiere responder*")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    BotClient().run(bot_config["BotToken"]) #Online para Discord
    #ConsoleChat()  #Offline desde Consola
```

Sigo sin resolver el problema de `NoneType object has no attribute 'send'`. cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Comment: Esta bien que pongas el progreso que tienes pero, el error sigue siendo el mismo?, te recomiendo que actualices la pregunta y pongas solo lo relevante

Comment: es que el error sigue siendo siempre el mismo, cambiar las "supuestas soluciones". pero todas me sale el AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute ....

Estaba pensando en abrir otra pregunta para no hacer tan larga esta, pero el tema es que estuve probando soluciones mias, y de los comentarios, pero no salgo del mismo error

Comment: mmm... bueno, al `NoneType` es por que algo te devuelve el valor de `None` y pues `None` no tiene un atributo `send`, Se regresa `None` cuando no hay un valor, debes verificar que al obtener el canal, este no sea `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrisik Vocal.
Si tu bot tiene acceso a todos los canales y este mismo canal que intentas alcanzar existe, te puedo asegurar que el problema específico que estás teniendo es por una falta del intent necesario para usar `bot.get_channel(id)`. También tengo unas recomendaciones para mejorar tu código y evitar futuros problemas.

### Solución

Al definir `commands.Bot()` también debes pasarle el intent `guilds` y así podrás usar `bot.get_channel`.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.none() # Crea un objeto de intents con todos deshabilitados.

intents.guilds= True
# O...
intents = discord.Intents(guilds=True)

# Finalmente lo pasas como argumento al definir el cliente:
commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)
```

Puedes ver una [guía en Inglés](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) sobre esto, y una [lista entera](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents) de todos los intents de la última versión.

### Recomendaciones y aclaraciones

- Debes definir el cliente `discord.ext.commands.Bot()` fuera
  de cualquier comando porque para definir un comando debes usarlo. Usualmente
  se coloca al inicio del código.
- El decorador `@bot.command()` es necesario para definir un comando (y
  previamente debe estar definido el cliente), así que quítale el
  comentario para que funcione como tal y no como una función común.
- Recomiendo que actualices tu librería de discord.py
  usando `pip install discord.py --upgrade` ya que los intents que
  necesitas podrían no estar en la versión que usas y podrían faltarte
  características o mejoras de la librería.
- Juzgando cómo llamaste al argumento de `time_messege(args)`, quiero
  aclarar que allí recibirías el contexto del comando, no un argumento
  que envíe el usuario, así que cuidado.
- Te recuerdo que discord.py no permite el bloqueo del código,
  por lo que bucles como While o comandos como o funciones como time.sleep() si
  son ejecutados por mucho tiempo podrían hacer que se detenga la
  ejecución del comando. Una alternativa válida a `time.sleep()` sería
  `asyncio.sleep()` de la librería asyncio, este no causa conflictos.
  Aún así, yo personalmente usaría `tasks.loop()` (una bucle de
  discord.ext que se ejecuta cada cierto periodo de tiempo en el fondo) para
  revisar el horario cada 1 minuto o 1 segundo. [Podrías echarle un
  vistazo](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html).
- Por último, si lo que quieres es enviar un string al azar de varios
  en tu mensaje, puedes usar `random.choice` del módulo random, y que
  elija uno de tus strings de una lista o tupla.

```py
# CÓDIGO MODIFICADO BASADO EN MIS RECOMENDACIONES
import time, random, discord, asyncio # Importo asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents(guilds=True)) # Uso el segundo método para establecer los intents

@bot.command()
async def time_messege(ctx): # Se le suele llamar así a este primer argumento en la documentación, no es obligatorio pero sirve para guiarse
    
    alarmtime = "11:13"
    
    #El comando espera el id del canal en forma de un entero, no en forma de cadena
    greeting_channel = bot.get_channel(814238156396298310)

    while True:
      
        lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

        if lcltime == alarmtime:

            #aca pondria el code de detectar canal y enviar
            print("is time!")

            hello_strings = ("@everyone Holi!, como estan chic@s?", "@everyone Holi!, Como va su dia? que me cuentan?", "everyone Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?", "@everyone Holi!, como se encuentran?") # Pongo las opciones de texto en una tupla y luego elijo una al azar con random.choice

            await greeting_channel.send(random.choice(hello_strings))

            await asyncio.sleep(90)

        else:
            print("not yet")
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder estube probando tu solucion y otras y no logro hacerlo anda, aun asi en la actualizacion de la pregunta puse que me sigue saliendo el mismo error. No se si se te ocurre algo.

Comment: @ElectrisikVocal Por desgracia no se me ocurre cuál es el problema. ¿Estás seguro de que el bot tiene acceso a ver el canal? ¿Actualizaste la librería discord.py?

Comment: El canal es un canal nuevo creado sin restricciones y el bot no tiene ninguna restriccion particular, la libreria de discord.py esta actualizada. La verdad muchas gracias por la ayuda, si llegase a poder hacerlo andar lo comento asi queda el tema y le sirve a alguno que lo lea.

Comment: @ElectrisikVocal el bot tiene los permisos necesarios de parte del servidor?

Comment: si si de hecho ese bot en otro script puede responder comentarios en cualquier canal y por privado si un user le escribe

Comment: ahora pongo una ectualizacion de la pregunta donde pongo el main.py del programa ahi si puede enviar info. pero esta parte esta en un thread para no chocar con la espera de mensajes

Comment: @Joakamine ahi quedo el main.py lo curioso es que de ahi si envia mensajes

Answer (score 1):

## Explicación del primer error

Como el error te dice, el client (objeto que representa a tu bot) no tiene el método send_message. Supongo que tu intención es enviar un mensaje al canal especifico.
Para eso NO es buena idea iniciar una nueva conexión con el comando `discord.Client`, ya que tu bot es conectado en esta línea `commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')`.

Puedes iniciar el bot con la extensión de la api, o con discord.Client, pero usar ambos no es buena idea.

Recurras o no a discord.Client, para enviar el mensaje tendrás que obtener un objeto que represente al canal donde querés enviarlo y aplicar en ese objeto el método send. Cosa que no haces.

En conclusión, yo descartaría por completo el primer código y me quedaría con el segundo.

## Explicación del segundo error

Tu problema se debe a que el comando `bot.get_channel("814238156396298310")` te devuelve None.
Por que? Por que el comando no logró encontrar el canal que especificaste.

A que se debe esto?

El comando espera el id del canal en forma de un entero, no en forma de cadena.

Todo esto lo se gracias a la documentación de discord.py. Ahora te paso el link con la información del comando: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel

## Solución del segundo error

Sabiendo esto, la solución resulta ser de lo más sencillo. Simplemente quita las comillas para que Python interprete el id del canal como un entero.

```
greeting_channel = bot.get_channel(814238156396298310)
```

Comment: Recien lo probe poner el id como un valor numerico (sin las comillas), pero me sale el error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

En la actualizacion de la pregunta puse el error, que es el mismo

Comment: @ElectrisikVocal revisaste si escribiste bien el id del canal? Quizá el id no es correcto.

Comment: Ese error se debe como supongo que sabrás a que sigue sin encontrar el canal.

Comment: es bastante curioso, osea active el modo dev de discord y copie y pegue textual el code del canal, creo que debe ser si o si correcto, no?